# Deploy multiple services to subdomains using Docker and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a docker compose file I'd like to use to deploy two versions of the same Django website on ECS to the same public domain (i.e. two separate "latest" and "prod" image tag versions as two separate docker services).

Using the configuration below, docker compose generates a single loadbalancer for the two services, but I'm able to access `latest` and `prod` on two different ports of the loadbalancer (and via Route 53):

```yaml
x-common-variables: &vars
 ....

services:
  web-prod:
    image: foo/bar:prod
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    environment: *vars

  web-latest:
    image: foo/bar:latest
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    environment: *vars
```

Is there any way to instead deploy `prod` and `latest` as `www.mydomain.com` and a separate `preview.mydomain.com` at the DNS layer instead? I'm assuming this would require separate load balancers for each service?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you create multiple clusters one for dev and another for production (you can do the same using the same cluster having multiple services but I'd like to have each environment separated in a different cluster)

After doing the above I'd suggest below steps:

- create an ECR image for `dev` and `prod` by running the below for each environment:

```
docker tag "web-app:latest" "${replace-by-ecr-uri}/web-app:latest-${replace-by-dev-or-prod}"
aws ecr get-login-password --region "${region-of-ecs}" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "${replace-by-ecr-uri}"
docker push "${replace-by ecr-uri}/web-app:latest-${replace-by-dev-or-prod}"
```

- create a task definition for each environment (`dev-webapp` and `prod-webapp`) and choose the respective image pushed in the first step
- create a service called `dev-webapp` in the `dev-cluster` and another called `prod-webapp` in the `prod-cluster`
- navigate to AWS Route53 and point `preview.mydomain.com` to the `dev-webapp` ELB and `www.mydomain.com` to the `prod-webapp` ELB

Comment: How do you handle cases where a dev runs `docker compose down` which deletes the ELB associated with that cluster?